# DTMC random walk model

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a discrete Markov chain random walk with p < 0.5 with state space S= {0,1,2..}
What is the stationary distribution?

I could use any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is the probability of being in position $n$, use first-step analysis to get
$$
a_n=p a_{n-1} + (1-p)a_{n+1},\quad n\ge 1,\quad\text{and}
$$
$$
a_0=(1-p)a_0+(1-p)a_1.
$$
This can then be readily solved for the $a_n$.